# Email client with support for multiple accounts and From addresses

Tags: gratis, android, email, imap

I’m looking for an email client (IMAP) for Android, which supports

- multiple accounts, and
- multiple *From* addresses per account (aka. identities, aliases).

When composing a new email, it must be possible to choose a *From* address. It would be great if there is no default, so the user has to make a choice.

When answering an email, the client should automatically choose the *From* address the original email was sent to. But it should also be possible to change the *From* address manually.

Gratis is required, FLOSS would be great.

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend you **K-9 Mail**, available for free at [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9), [Aptoide](http://m.aptoide.com/app/5550616), and **[F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.fsck.k9)** (which shows it's FOSS):

- *Supports multiple accounts:* Yes (I'm using it with 3 different accounts currently)
- *Multiple "From" addresses per account:* Yes, it's called "Aliases". I didn't use that yet on *K-9*, so I cannot tell how well it works concerning "no default" and "auto-select"
- *IMAP support:* Yes, with the choice of Push & Pull (IMAP Idle versus Poll) (all my accounts are using that), POP3 as well (just in case)
- *Gratis, FOSS:* Yes, yes

[image: K-9 account overview] [image: K-9 folder view]
<sup>*K-9 Mail:* Account overview, Folder view (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9); click images for larger variants)</sup>

These two screenshots nicely demonstrate the features you requested (well, most of them): Multiple accounts (first screenshot), and even a "unified inbox" for all of them ("virtual"; you can assign colors to your accounts to distinguish them here).

For alternatives, be welcome to my list of [Email Apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=107), where you can also find reviews, video demos, and more linked to the apps. And a ton of addons/widgets/… for *K-9 Mail* as well.

Answer (score 1):

AquaMail also supports multiple accounts and [multiple aliases](https://www.aqua-mail.com/forum/index.php?topic=1325.0).

[image: 2]

Not to mention it exists for many years and has plethora of other features.